# Laravel Cashier paymentMethods() return always empty object result

Tags: php, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

- Cashier Version: ^10.5
- Laravel Version: ^6.0
- PHP Version:  7.3.5
- Database Driver & Version:

#### Description:

paymentMethods() retrieve always array with empty object.

```
public function userAllPaymentMethods(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::find(5);
        $paymentMethod = $user->paymentMethods();
        return response($paymentMethod);
    }
```

Result : 
https://www.screencast.com/t/aqenaud77A

Also  using Stripe PaymentMethod lib it's works.

```
public function userAllPaymentMethods(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::find(5);
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('{{KEY}}');
        $paymentMethod = \Stripe\PaymentMethod::all([
            'customer' =>  $user->stripe_id,
            'type' => 'card',
        ]);

        return response($paymentMethod);
    }
```

Result :
https://www.screencast.com/t/X14ane7WyqS

GitHub : [here](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/issues/821)

Answer (score 8):

```
$paymentMethods = $user->paymentMethods()->map(function($paymentMethod){
        return $paymentMethod->asStripePaymentMethod();
    });
```

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution:

```
$paymentMethods = [];

foreach ($user->paymentMethods() as $paymentMethod) {
    $paymentMethods[] = $paymentMethod->asStripePaymentMethod();
}
```

Just loop through the payment methods and using `$paymentMethod->asStripePaymentMethod()` will get the payment methods for the user.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. didn't have time to investigate in deep. I just realized that method `paymentMethod` in `cashier/src/Billable.php` returns nothing.

```php
/**
     * Get a collection of the entity's payment methods.
     *
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection|\Laravel\Cashier\PaymentMethod[]
     */
    public function paymentMethods($parameters = [])
    {
        $this->assertCustomerExists();

        $parameters = array_merge(['limit' => 24], $parameters);

        // "type" is temporarily required by Stripe...
        $paymentMethods = StripePaymentMethod::all(
            ['customer' => $this->stripe_id, 'type' => 'card'] + $parameters,
            $this->stripeOptions()
        );

        return collect($paymentMethods->data)->map(function ($paymentMethod) {
            return new PaymentMethod($this, $paymentMethod);
        });
    }
```

`return new PaymentMethod($this, $paymentMethod);` this will return nothing instead of $paymentMethod. The solution for me was to overwrite PaymentMethod in mu user model the same way you did with stripe Lib.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to stripe, I think you are getting the right data, the problem is $paymentMethod is not encodable to JSON, that's why you get an empty response, try adding dd($paymentMethod); before the return statement and check the result.